# Python 3.6 - I need IDEAS to optimize this chunk of code and make it cleaner

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

This is what I currently have. Briefly its purpose is part of a bigger program to take psuedocode and turn it into a game board.

```
FIRST_LAYER_CODE = [] # This is where the psuedocode goes.

def irrelevant_name(tilesMade, xCoordinate, yCoordinate):
    # There is some other stuff in this function, but it is not relevant to the question.
    elif FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3] == "BLC":
        for i in range(2):
            for j in [0, (1/3), (2/3)]:
                Rectangle(Point(xCoordinate + j, yCoordinate + j), Point(xCoordinate + j + (1/3) + (i * (1 - (j + (1/3)))), yCoordinate + 1 - (i * ((2/3) - j)))).draw(window)
    elif FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3] == "BRC":
        for i in range(2):
            for j in [1, (2/3), (1/3)]:
                Rectangle(Point(xCoordinate + j, yCoordinate + 1 - j), Point(xCoordinate + j - (1/3) - (i * (j - (1/3))), yCoordinate + 1 - (i * (j - (1/3))))).draw(window)
    elif FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3] == "TLC":
        for i in range(2):
            for j in [0, (1/3), (2/3)]:
                Rectangle(Point(xCoordinate + j, yCoordinate + 1 - j), Point(xCoordinate + j + (1/3) + (i * (1 - (j + (1/3)))), yCoordinate + (i * ((2/3) - j)))).draw(window)
    elif FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3] == "TRC":
        for i in range(2):
            for j in [1, (2/3), (1/3)]:
                Rectangle(Point(xCoordinate + j, yCoordinate + j), Point(xCoordinate + j - (1/3) - (i * (j - (1/3))), yCoordinate + (i * (j - (1/3))))).draw(window)
```

This code works as intended, but I always see people have more stylish code, and more importantly better optimized code. What are some things I can do to simplify this chunk of code? I AM NOT ASKING FOR YOU TO GIVE ME ANY CODE!!! I JUST WANT IDEAS TO OPTIMIZE THIS CODE BECAUSE I AM NEW TO PROGRAMMING!!! (The caps are not a mean gesture, but I don't want people saying that I'm just asking for code.)

Now I know the first suggestion I get will be that the for loops seem repetitive and that I should make a new function that has the for loops and makes the rectangle, but the problem is the part that makes the new rectangle is different for each loop, and I can not pass through arguments such as (1 - j) because j would not be declared yet.

I have been thinking about this for a while, and have come up with nothing. I just need ideas please and of course THANK-YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key here is removing duplicates

1. You duplicate `FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3]`.  You could make a local variable here
2. Since you always want to `for i in range(2)`, you refactor that up a level and do your `if`s inside the loop body.
3. The next thing that's duplicated is the `for j in [0, (1/3), (2/3)]: ... Rectangle(Point(xCoordinate + j, yCoordinate + ...` stuff. The only thing that really changes in these lines is the first list item (0 for "BLC", 1 for "BRC", etc) and the things you add/subtract from the coordinates. Instead of repeating the `for j in (...` and `Rectangle(Point..)` stuff for each block, just modify local variables that you use afterward.

   ```py
   def irrelevant():
       letters = FIRST_LAYER_CODE[tilesMade][0:3] == "BLC"
       offsets = []
       if letters == "BLC"
           offsets = [0, 1/3, 2/3, 0,0, 1/3, -1, ...]
       elif letters = "BRC"
           offsets = [1, 2/3, 1/3, 1, ...]
       for i in range(2):
           for j in [offsets[0], offsets[1], offsets[2]]:
               Rectangle(Point(x + offsets[3])...draw()
   ```

   Where `offsets` are the numbers added/multiplied you use in your `Point` math and in your `for j` loop.

   You can take advantage of the fact that `1 - j` = `1 + (-1)*j` and `1 + j` = `1 + (1)*j` to basically always do addition just use 1 or -1 as a "j multiplier".

   This will quickly get hard to keep track of, though, so you may want to use a named-item dictionary to keep the offset values clear.

   ```
   offsets = { 'topleft': 1, .... }
   ...
   ```
4. Going even further, you could define a dictionary based on the 3 letters as the key and store offset values there.

   ```
   offsets = {'BLC': { 'topleft': 1, ... }, 'BRC': }
   ```

   This would let you avoid the `ifs` and instead just do a dictionary lookup. With this in place your method would be about 3 lines plus whatever you need to represent your "control" data (`offsets`).

Hope I've left you plenty to think on and hope this is helpful and clear.

Comment: This is truly a great response. Thank you so much, I'm working on implementing this right now.